# How to disable a div

Tags: jquery

Hi 
I have a `div` container having some string,Some child div have a text like "**Welcome**", I want to make that container `div` disabled i.e not clickable, If that container child `div` have "**Welcome**" string.
My Markup is like this.

```
<div>
<span>some text</span>
<span>some text</span>
    <div>
        <span>some text</span>
        <span>some text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       Welcome
    </div>
    <div>
       Welcome
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There is no jquery here - is your question missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled or not clickable? There isn't anything in a div by itself to make it unclickable.

Comment: there are n number of divs, so ones a user selected a div I add a text on that div is "welcome". Now if that div show in the list not again it not be selected by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div:contains("Welcome")')
  .prop('disabled', true);
```

Or if you want to do only divs that have exactly `Welcome`.

```
$('div:contains("Welcome")').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == 'Welcome';
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

It [appears](http://jsbin.com/ovama4/edit) clicking a `disabled="disabled"` element still fires its click event.

So you can `off('click')` instead, and leave the `disabled` if you like for semantic reasons (and as a CSS hook, i.e. `div[disabled]`).

Comment: i don't think you can disable a click event just like that. and also if there was another element e.g. "you're welcome" that would include that element aswell.

Comment: @Val: The second code example covers that. He also says child has text **like** `Welcome`. That is ambiguous, so I provided two solutions,.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable a div, give it the class name "disabled", e.g.:

```
<div class="disabled">Whatever</div>
```

Then you can hook into all disabled divs' click events to prevent it from handling.

```
$('div.disabled').live('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  // you might not want this depending on your intentions
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m no sure I understood your question, I hope this is what youre looking for:

```
 $("a").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).hide("slow");
 });
```

Please comment if not

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using this as welcome message once user is logged in ... if user is loggedin you would have a link there... if is logged in then the user would just read welcome...

you need to do this on the server side scripting instead of client side.

anyways if you still need a client side solution.

```
$('div').each(function (){
  if($this.text().trim()=='Welcome'){
     $(this).click(function (){return false;})
  }
});
```

It would be a good idea if you use a `class` name as this is far better than just checking all the divs... the trim will remove all the white spaces before and after. so hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as assigning the attribute "disabled=disabled" to the DIV element. That will gray it out, but all elements in the DIV are still accessible and clickable. To truly disable the contents in the DIV, you have to select all descendants in the DIV...

```
$("div#your-id *").find(function(index) {
 // the jQuery find function will find all descendants inside the DIV
});
```

and then have to disable each found element. But even that isn't as simple as assigning the attribute "disabled=disabled" because some elements don't respond to the "disabled" attributes, such as links.  Elements with click events assigned will not be disabled by assigning "disabled=disabled".  You have to remove all events on all elements in the DIV.

I created a jQuery plugin that can completely disable the content inside a DIV.  With my plugin, you simply need to do this..

```
$("div#your-id").disabler({
  disable : true
});
```

and all elements in the DIV will be really disabled.  Use it or rip the code out of it and get ideas from it.  ( http://www.dougestep.com/dme/jquery-disabler-widget ).